# How to get value from a textbox that being autocompleted in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

There is a textbox that being autocompleted on load.
Suppose that it is a email textboxl

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var email = $("#txtEmail").text();

    });
```

I try to get the value by this code, but it always return null. how to get that email value being autocomplted ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var email = $("#txtEmail").val()`

Answer (score 3):

You use `.val()` for that:

```
var email = $("#txtEmail").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use if only one input type this  link other wise use
$("id of emial field").val();
[if you have only one input type on your page you can use:](http://jsfiddle.net/anupam/5Z643/)

Answer (score 1):

For retrieving value from a input field like textarea, text you have to use `val()` and for getting value form a regular html tag like label, span, h1, h2 etc you have to use `text()`

```
$('#input_textarea').val(); //right way
$('#input_textarea').text(); // wrong way.returns null

$('#regular_html_tag').text(); // right way
$('#regular_html_tag').val(); // wrong way.It returtns NaN (not a number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yFQu4/1/) .. i think this is what you actually want

**UPDATES**

check one more [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Cu9s/)